# Windows XP installation fails because of bad key

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, windows-installation

My computer was wiped clean before I installed XP, but my key was bad.

I bought Windows 7 (downloadable) but the computer keeps trying to run XP. But since the install failed, I'm stuck.

I just want to delete XP and install Windows 7.

Answer (score 0):

If you purchased a Windows 7 upgrade only version, then you may be stuck. The only way workaround would be to purchase a valid version XP from ebay or similar..

Comment: "only workaround"? Says who? You *can* clean install using Win7 upgrade media.

Comment: My point was about getting a valid key, not about clean installs. @Karan _Can_ you do a clean install without a _valid_ XP key? If so, then I stand corrected.